# VueJs and chaining actions and promisses

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, es6-promise

On my component I have 2 actions on mounted which on their own would fetch data from backend, and each of them also need to call mutations.
The problem is the second mutation is dependent on result of first call
I need to make sure that it is the case, at the moment sometimes the second call ends before first call.

Component

```
methods: {
    ...mapActions([
        'fetchTypesOne',
        'fetchTypesTwo'
   ])
},
mounted() {
    this.fetchTypesOne()
    .then(this.fetchTypesTwo())
    .catch(errors => console.log(errors));
}
```

And my store

```
    actions: {
        fetchTypesOne({commit}) {
            return axios.get('url')
                .then(response => {
                    commit('MUTATION_ONE', response.data)
                })

        },
        fetchTypesTwo({commit}) {
            return axios.get('url2')
                .then(response => {
                    commit('MUTATION2', response.data);
                })
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

`.then(someFunction())`

the function `someFunction()` is immediately executed and it's supposed to return a function. And that returned function will be executed after the promise is resolved. Try doing

`then(someFunction)` without the trailing parentheses or
`then(() => someFunction())`.

Also I don't think that's how you're supposed to call store functions. At least that's not how I see it in the documentation : https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#composing-actions

Comment: writing mounted like this fixed it for me
```
  this.fetchShiftTypes()
    .then(this.fetchPlannedShifts);
```

Comment: Good :) it's a common mistake I still fall for it from time to time, when you're supposed to pass a function as an argument, remember to not pass the result of the function instead